# Method of undetermined coefficients clarification

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For $$\ddot{x}+x=\epsilon$$ I found that $x(t)=c_1\sin(t)+c_2\cos(t)$. Next for method of undetermined coefficients we have \begin{align*}
x&=At^2+Bt+C\\
\dot{x}&=2At+B\\
\ddot{x}&=2A.
\end{align*} According to my solutions manual for $\ddot{x}+x=\epsilon$ we have $2A+At^2+Bt+C=\epsilon$ or $x=\epsilon$. My question is how did we just confirm that $x=\epsilon$ in this case? I don't see how we made that conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify polynomials by the coefficient before each degree. For example here
$A=0$  because there's no term in $t^2$, and $B=0$ because there's no term in $t$. However
$$
2A+C= \epsilon
$$
But with $A=0$ we have 
$C= \epsilon$. Replacing

> $$
> x=At^2+Bt+C=0+0+\epsilon
> $$

Answer (score 1):

Substituting the polynomial yielded, you can see by equating coefficients, that $x=\epsilon$ :

$$\ddot{At^2 + Bt + C} + At^2 + Bt + C = \epsilon \Rightarrow \begin{cases} A=0 \\ B = 0 \\C=\epsilon\end{cases}$$

Plugging in $x=\epsilon$ if $\epsilon$ is a constant in your equation, you simply get that

$$\ddot{\epsilon}+\epsilon= 0 + \epsilon = \epsilon$$

thus your initial differential equation is true and $x=\epsilon$ is indeed a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your right side is $ϵe^{0\cdot t}$ and as $0$ is not a root of the characteristic polynomial $0=\lambda^2+1$ of the left side, the method of undetermined coefficients tells you that the polynomial factor of the particular solution has the same degree $0$ with no extra factors $t$, so $x_p(t)=Ae^{0\cdot t}=A$. Inserting into the ODE gives $A=ϵ$, thus $x_p(t)=ϵ$.